# How to remove all (and by "all" I really mean "all") text in Plymouth boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, terminal

I recently installed the latest raspbian image on my Pi and configured it to boot to CLI with autologin. This version has the Pixel theme of Plymouth.

I followed all tutorials I could find on removing the text that shows on boot, but the spinning text of Plymouth still shows messages such as: "systemd-logind.service" or "Starting NPS Server".

***I need to remove those***. Do you have any idea how to configure Plymouth (or other software involved) in order to hide all this messages and warnings?

Please keep in mind that I do want to show the splash screen logo, which is already correctly configured. I'm quite happy with Plymouth regarding that. I *just* want to hide the text messages that keep spinning at boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change or edit your plymouth theme in order to remove theses strings.

You can look for less verbose plymouth themes with :

```
sudo plymouth-set-default-theme --list
```

And try them :

```
sudo plymouthd
sudo plymouth-set-default-theme joy
sudo plymouth --show-splash
sudo plymouth quit
```

If you need more flexibility, you can edit themes by modifying images : /usr/share/plymouth/themes/themeName

If you launch plymouth via initramfs, don't forget to update it !
This is the case if you have a line in your conft.txt file that starts with `initramfs=something`

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Comment: Not sure if these were the changes I did but I was able to remove all prints by editing the text callback function in the plymouth there files as you suggested